# Python intrepreter not showing up in Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

While using Pycharm there is no option for me to configure anything regarding the interpreter. In the bottom row there is not even an Interpreter-option, and if I open the settings menu there are no interpreter shown, even tho I have Conda and the system interpreter

example of the "missing Interpreter":
[image]

also in the right hand corner where always the interpreter option is also shown, it is not in this case:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the question needs details and clarity, a screenshot would be helpful since from the description alone it's not possible to be entirely sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

To add a Python interpreter into Pycharm, you must follow these steps:

1. Click on *File -> Settings*;
2. From the window that appears, click the *Project* tab, then *Python interpreter*;
3. From the informations that appear, click the + sign, above the package list;
4. A new window will appear, which displays all the available Python interpreters. Because you have none, let's add one;
5. Near the Python interpreter path, click the icon with a cogwheel. From the menu that appears, click *Add*;
6. From the appearing window you can add a new interpreter, by specifying the path to the Python executable.

Later edit: [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter) is a link to what you are looking for.

Comment: Sadly this is not working. if you look at my screenshots (i have just edit so you had no chance to see them earlier), the interpreter tab is totally empty

Comment: We had the same problem. The solution is to delete your project from PyCharm, quit PyCharm, delete the .idea folder then open it again as a new project. Then you can set the interpreter.